# android spinner in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, spinner

I know this isn't a proper question but I found nothing useful by googling.

I want a android spinner in my html page; I mean a value set by drop down list. I searched for  spinner in javaScript but that wasn't what I want.

Can you guys tell me what calls android spinner like element in html or give me link/tutorial?

Comment: what are you using phonegap?

Comment: Do you mean in Java, using the Android SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: we call select-box in html which we call as spinner in android.